# Why constexpr method can return correctly class members whose value change during execution?

Tags: c++, constexpr-function

I just discovered that a `constexpr` method **can return correctly the value of a class member that changes during execution**. My question is, how is this possible if `constexpr` methods are supposed to be evaluated completely at compile time?

The example below correctly outputs `Value: 0` and then `Value: 5`. Even more, if I change the `a.change(5)` to something unpredictible for the compiler (such as `a.change(atoi(argv[1]))` or `a.change(rand() % 10 + 1)` it still works. Why? Why does it even compile?

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:
        void change(int value) { x = value; }
        int get() const { return x; }
        constexpr int value() const noexcept { return x; }
    private:
        int x{0};
};

int main()
{
    A a;

    std::cout << "Value: "  << a.get() << std::endl;
    a.change(5);
    std::cout << "Value: "  << a.get() << std::endl;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You've mixed up [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) and [`consteval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval), only `consteval` is guaranteed to be evaluated compile-time

Comment: `constexpr` methods are "just" methods which **can** be called in constexpr contexts with appropriate arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example you're not even calling the `constexpr` function, you're calling `get`, which is not `constexpr`.

However, `constexpr` functions *can* be evaluated at compile time, but also during run time if compile time evaluation is not possible.

If you called `value` instead of `get`, it would still work and the function would be evaluated at run time.

In order to force compile time evaluation, you can write

```
constexpr auto val = a.value();
```

This will indeed give you an error if compile time evaluation is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

`constexpr` means that you can use that function in a core constant expression, as long as you have `constexpr` arguments for it. It can still be used in other contexts.

As it stands, you can't use `A::value` in a core constant expression, because you have no way of getting a `constexpr A`. If you instead had

```
class A
{
    public:
        constexpr A() = default;
        constexpr void change(int value) { x = value; }
        constexpr int get() const noexcept { return x; }
    private:
        int x{1};
};
```

You could write a function that modified an `A` at compile time.

```
constexpr int stuff(A a) {
    a.change(10);
    return a.get();
}
```

[See it on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/850df66b9b7b5131)

Answer (score 2):

`constexpr` functions in general are evaluated at compile-time **only if** they receive `constexpr` arguments, for methods it includes `this` pointer.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:
        void change(int value) { x = value; }
        constexpr int value() const noexcept { return x; }
    private:
        int x{0};
};

int main()
{
    constexpr const A foo;
    const A bar;// Const it not enough.

    static_assert(foo.value()==0);
    static_assert(bar.value()==0);// ERROR:  non-constant condition for static assertion
}
```

Comment: It is not the argument which make the call compile time or not, but the context (where is it is used). (it is generally a good hint for optimizer to optimize constexpr function with constexpr argument, but `constexpr` is not required anyway).